# Configuration of video device failed, falling back to default

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm writing a program to open my mac osx's facetime hd camera and get h264 data with ffmpeg, but i encounter encounter a hard problem at the first step.

```
AVFormatContext *Producer::OpenCamera()
{
    AVFormatContext *pContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVInputFormat *infmt = av_find_input_format("avfoundation");
    if (infmt != nullptr)
    {
        AVDictionary *paramDict = nullptr;
        av_dict_set(&paramDict, "video_device_index", "1", 0);
        av_dict_set(&paramDict, "video_size", "1280x720", 0);
        av_dict_set(&paramDict, "framerate", "30", 0);
        av_dict_set(&paramDict, "pixel_format", "yuyv422", 0);

        int ret = avformat_open_input(&pContext, "0", infmt, &paramDict);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "cannot open input" << std::endl;
            avformat_free_context(pContext);
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    return pContext;
}
```

When I call the function, I get the result below:

```
'<AVCaptureScreenInput: 0x7fe94ce18550>' opened
Configuration of video device failed, falling back to default.
```

Addtionally, when I set av_dict_set(&paramDict, "video_device_index", "0", 0); I'll get sig abort, which makes me confused. Can anyone help me?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you get the *"Configuration of video device failed"* whatever you do - I tried everything I can think of in Terminal with the `ffmpeg` executable. If anyone succeeds in screen-grabbing under macOS without this message, please ping me! Thanks.